# MediaPlayer prepare fail IOException

Tags: android, media-player, prepare

My question is does having too many MediaPlayers cause an IOException preparefailed: status= 0x1 to log?

The way my program is running is i use a separate instance of Media Player for each video I want to play. At the end of the run i stop the videoPlayer, release it, and turn it null; this is ok sometimes but other times when i move between video's too fast i get a IO exception and the video will not play. I also have a mediaPlayer playing some background music in a service.

Basically my Video activity gets a new call each time a file ends playback. Could this be the error and i should try to just reuse the same media player with a different file?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my own answer. I don't know if this is a good way to do it but:

```
if(videoFile != null)
        {
            Log.i("INITPLAYER", videoFile);
            afd = getAssets().openFd(videoFile);

            instructionVideoPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

            instructionVideoPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getDeclaredLength());

            instructionVideoPlayer.setDisplay(holder);

            instructionVideoPlayer.prepare();

            instructionVideoPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(instructionVideoComplete);
            instructionVideoPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        }
        else
            Log.i("VideoPlayer", "noVideoFile");

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.i(this.toString(), "IOEXception");
        e.printStackTrace();

//Here is the fix:
        instructionVideoPlayer.release();
        instructionVideoPlayer = null;
        initPlayer();
// reinit after prepare failed. although this can bring in an infinte loop if video file does not exits
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.i("InitPlayer", e.getClass().toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: That really helped me too . just calling the release. !